# form validation + json parse

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

so i got a contacts.json file in which i'll store what i will submit from my form in the contact page. The 'storing' works well, just i want to add a validation to it, and only after that validation to be able to send and store those so called contacts. here's what i have:

```
app.js:
app.post('/contact', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    const contacts_path = __dirname + '/privat/contacts.json';
    const contactDataJson = fs.readFileSync(contacts_path);
    const json_data = JSON.parse(contactDataJson);
    const contact = {
        email: req.body.email,
        content: req.body.content

    }
    json_data["contacts"].push(contact);
    fs.writeFileSync(contacts_path, JSON.stringify(json_data));
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static/contact.html');
});
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <form method="POST" action="/contact">
            <h1>Share your thoughts!</h1>
            <p>Email</p>
            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Type here your email" type="text"><br><br>
            <p>Tell us what you think about us!</p>
            <textarea id="content" name="content" class="contactarea" rows="10" placeholder="What would you like to talk about?"></textarea><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn"> 
                <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>submit
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What issue are you looking to solve?

Comment: i made a function to "validate" my contact, for example for the email 
```function emailValid(){ 
var x = document.getElementById("email").value
if(x.includes(@gmail.com) != true){
text = "input a valid mail";} }``` 
but i don't know how to implement that in my app.js, to validate my form and only after a successful validation my data to be stored in contacts.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation you want to do is on the client side, so you need to perform it before the form is posted to your backend service (`app.js`). In order to do so, you can add a handler to the submit action, which would invoke the validation method and then submit the form. Something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/contact">
            <h1>Share your thoughts!</h1>
            <p>Email</p>
            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Type here your email" type="text"><br><br>
            <p>Tell us what you think about us!</p>
            <textarea id="content" name="content" class="contactarea" rows="10" placeholder="What would you like to talk about?"></textarea><br><br>
            <button class="btn" id="submitBtn"> <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>submit</button>
        </form>

<script>
var button = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // prevents the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault(); 
    
    emailValid();
    // other validations you want to add

    var form = document.findElementById('myForm');
    form.submit();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate the email address in your HTML, you can do this:

```
<input id="email" name="email" onkeyup="emailValid()" placeholder="Type here your email" type="text">
<script>
function emailValid() {
    var emailaddr = document.getElementById("email").value
    if (emailaddr.includes("@gmail.com") !== true) {
        emailaddr.value = "Invalid Email Address";
        return false;
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

To validate the email on submission, just call the emailValid() function in your script that runs on submission.